# Getting data from secured website

Tags: https

I am working on a project which needs to extract title and description of every website by parsing its html and getting the content out of title tag and meta description. am successful and parsing that data from normal website, but my code is not able to open website with `https` protocol and couldn't parse data from them. is there any way my code can open those websites like blogger.com, irctc.co.in etc which runs on https?

Comment: which technology are you using?

Comment: is there any credentials needed?

Comment: I am using php, I dont need anything else other then title and description of these websites.

Comment: use CURL, search what do you want using CURL in php on google.com